# MappingNotFound exception while programmatically adding entities

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a requirement of dynamically adding Entity classes(annotation driven, without hbm file) into persistence.

I have tried below approach to add entities dynamically.

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
                .addClass(org.entity.Person.class);
```

I got MappingNotFoundException: Mapping(RESOURCE) not found : org.entity.Person.hbm.xml

Is there any other way to do this?

I have gone through lot of posts but I did not find exact solution to my problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addClass` method looks up for the mapping file

> Read a mapping as an application resource using the convention that a
>   class named foo.bar.Foo is mapped by a file foo/bar/Foo.hbm.xml which
>   can be resolved as a classpath resource.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addClass-java.lang.Class-

If you want to add an annotated class you should use [`addAnnotatedClass`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addAnnotatedClass-java.lang.Class-)

> ```
>  public Configuration addAnnotatedClass(Class annotatedClass)
>  // Read metadata from the annotations associated with this class.
>  Parameters:
>     annotatedClass - The class containing annotations
>  Returns:
>     this (for method chaining)
> ```

For example:

```
 Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
            .addAnnotatedClass(org.entity.Person.class);
```